# rails paperclip: How to access the url of the a

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, paperclip

I am new to rails and paperclip plugin - so I apologize if this is as a silly question.

I am trying to upload a file and later access the url for the file url. In dev, the file gets stored locally while in prod, the file is pushed to s3.

Once the model is stored in the db, how to I get the url later on to display the link?

Comment: I was making a mistake of directly accessing the url. So if the model is model and the paperclip attachment name is attachment then I was accessing the url as model.url instead of model.attachment.url. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify a paperclip association in a model you do :

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :thumbnail, :styles => { :medium => "300x300#", :thumb => "100x100#"} , :default_url => '/images/default/missing.png'
end
```

To get the url, you have to do :

```
@model.thumbnail.url(:original)
```

Where :original is the file format, it can be :medium, :thumb...

Comment: Thanx. yeah, I was accessing the above @model.url by mistake. I would mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I have a question is that how can i access the default_url if nothing found?